# How to stop spiders from crawling every combination of multiple drop-down pages

Tags: search, caching

We have a site with around 10,000 pages and media items (mainly PDFs)

We use various tools to catalog, check and report on our site and, of course we encourage *good* spiders (Google et al.).

The problem we find is on pages which have SOLr search options.  When they have mutliple filter drop downs, spiders will find EVERY POSSIBLE COMBINATION of those and so our site suddenly becomes a 300,000 page site. In addition, almost one of those hits goes sailing past the (Varnish) Cache, so it makes a real impact on the server. So my logs are full of lines like this:

`"GET http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/resources?f%5B0%5D=programs%3A991&f%5B1%5D=type%3A11&f%5B2%5D=type%3A578 HTTP/1.1"`

It's annoying when every piss-pot little spam spider takes up major resources like this.

Anyone have an idea? Google has nothing....

Comment: 1. Programatically add meta noindex tags to the relevant pages, and rel nofollow to the facet/filter links. This will catch good bots. 2. Give it a week or something after that, and then search your access logs for traffic that continues to follow a pattern of crawling those URLs, even though you've told them not to. Those are the bad bots. Identify a pattern from their user agent string, and use it to ban at web server level

Comment: That's a good suggestion - I think if you publish a proper sitemap then you are entitled to be more aggressive with your Crawl directives and then block/restrict anyone who doesnt play ball. I use a small spurious error page (417) that says something about "server being overloaded/please stop crawling" when they annoy me - I put in a short delay before it's displayed just to mess with them more.